# Excel input and output into same cell

Tags: excel, vba

I searched online for a solution but nothing came up. All the answers were for single targets cells.

The thing I want to do is the following, in Range `L1:L1000` if I input something into a cell in this range then it gets added to the following formula  `=IF(N1=0;"";INPUT)` - in the same cell.

So lets say I type `Hello` into `L1` then the formula becomes `=IF(N1=0;"";"Hello")`

If anyone could help me that would be awesome since my understanding of VB is very very basic and I am just learning it.

Comment: That isn't possible. A cell can't change its own contents. You could do something like that with VBA - in effect permitting the user to enter "Hallo" but not "Hello". Using worksheet functions, you might have a formula in the adjacent cell, like, [M1]=IF(AND(N1=0,L1="Hello"),"Wrong answer","")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event when the cell is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("L1:L1000")) Is Nothing) Then
         'E.g.: Here comes your code for Cell L1
          Target.Formula = "=IF(N1=0,""""," & Target.Text & ")"
    End If 

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This method sets the formular of the edited cell to `=IF(N1=0;"";INPUT)`.

Comment: just modify your `Target.Formular` to `Target.Formula`

Comment: Also, you have one `=` too many, modify to `"=IF(N1=0,""""," & Target.Text & ")"` . Also, add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end (not to enter the `Change` event multiple times. AND....`Range("L1:L100")` - according to PO

Comment: Thanks for this, however it gives me the error:Invalid use of property (I hope this is the correct errormessage since I have Excel in Dutch).
It has to do with Target.Formula

Comment: There was a missing equal sign in line `Target.Formula...`. I've corrected it.